# Visual Inheritance

Tags: .net, oop, inheritance

I have same settings for all of my forms
for example color , font , align, etc
How can i do these settings for one form and inheriting it on all forms.
thanks.
Edition 1 :
i am using Windows Forms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to extend/inherit from the form class, set the properties the way you like in your constructor, and let your forms inherit from that class.

Something like:

```
class RedForm : Form
{
    public RedForm() { BackColor = Color.Red; }
}
```

and then make your forms based on RedForm rather than Form.

Comment: Thanks.
WHich one better? extend or inherit?
you said : "set the properties the way you like in your constructor"
Where?
please give me small sample for inheriting.

Comment: @shaahin: Extend and inherit mean the same thing in this case -- to create a subclass.  It's just that some languages use "extend" and some "inherit", and you didn't specify the language.

Comment: thank you.
please describe more about your answer.
and give me small sample if possible.